# How to Separate Factors

Tags: probability

I had baked a Chocolate cake for tomorrow's breakfast.

Sadly, I was run out of baking sodas, I just put in baking powders only(usually I need both of them working together to rise the dough well up).

By the way, also, I had added one more eggs compared to the usual days recipe because I just want more egg-flavors in it.

The result was terrible. Taste was not bad but the bread absolutely hasn't well risen up as I had expected and compared to the usual recipe.

So I had written down as below:

$$P(\overline{B}\mid(\overline{S_d}, E_{gg})) = 1  \tag1$$

where

$\overline{B} = \text{bread not risen up well}$

$\overline{S_d}= \text{baking soda not added}$

$E_{gg} = \text{addtional egg than usual}$

From this point,

I would like to calculate each of $P(\overline{B}\mid\overline{S_d}) \tag2$ and $P(\overline{B}\mid E_{gg}) \tag3$.

How can represent $(1)$ with using the terms $(2)$ and $(3)$

Comment: Not nearly enough information to conclude anything.

Comment: When people comes into this case what kind of additional experiment required?

Comment: This leaves the realm of mathematics and enters the realm of experiment design and culinary arts and is not in my opinion suitable for this site.  Unless if you were to use other people's work, experiments, and results you would need to estimate each of $P(\overline{B}\mid \overline{S_d})$ and $P(\overline{B}\mid E_{gg})$ individually, ideally by having that be the only thing that's wrong with the recipe.  I will point out as well that your *one single* experiment with no baking soda and one too many egg does not necessarily imply that it will be bad every time.  Need more trials for that.

Comment: But I actually want to know how the first equation decomposed into the form which contains the last two terms.. isn't it well-revealed yet? I had changed OP with this intention

Comment: Even if we were to assume that $P(\overline{B}\mid \overline{S_d},E_{gg})=1$ exactly, the fact that $P(A\mid B\cap C)=1$ does not give enough information as to $P(A\mid B)$ or $P(A\mid C)$ and either could be as low as $0\%+\epsilon$ or as high as $100\%$ where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrarily small number.

Comment: If your question is, given $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(A\mid C)$, calculate $P(A\mid B\cap C)$ there is still not enough information.

Comment: How did you get eqn(1) and what tells you that it is correct? The RHS may be anything between 0 and 1. Just because I tossed a coin today and got a head doesnt mean that the coin is biased towards head and the probability of getting a head is 1.